# Is there any online learning seminar or course on category theory.

Tags: category-theory, self-learning, online-resources

Background: Currently, Msc mathematics with an algebra background, which includes Abstract algebra, Representation theory, and Commutative algebra.
I did go through Prof. Richard Broched's lectures on youtube https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PL8yHsr3EFj51F9XZ_Ka4bLnQoxTdMx0AL and corresponding topics from (Mac Lane's) book on category theory.
Is there any learning seminar or online course starting in the next 2-3 months at most? I want to work in this direction for my Ph.D.(and some applications to algebraic geometry and representation theory in particular). So I expect some questions from this in Ph.D. interviews.

Comment: i'll recommend "Category Theory" by Awodey and "Sets for mathematics" by Lawvere.  These are books, not online courses.

Comment: It's not a course, but the The Catsters made some nice videos: https://www.youtube.com/user/TheCatsters

Comment: I've voted to close as "personal advice" specifically because of the cue "Is there any learning seminar or online course starting in the next 2-3 months at most?" which limits the usefulness of this question in the future.  As for references for learning category theory, I think we have ample posts for that already.

Comment: I don't understand anything about this book, but I am aware of it. It seems like it may align with your interests: https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/~hkrause/HomTheRep.pdf

Comment: if you speak Italian or you're willing to learn, there's this :) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DIXypXx8-DE&list=PLwOJoZOlTAm-rQUkbmfyDMsLk7-JDy5Vm covers pretty much all the fundamentals!